# Tough integral from particle physics

Tags: definite-integrals, fourier-transform

I have been struggling to check if it's even possible to calculate the following integral
$$
\iiint_{\Bbb R^3} d^3 \textbf{q} {1\over \sqrt{E_{\textbf{p}+\textbf{q}}(E_{\textbf{p}+\textbf{q}}+m)}}e^{-i E_{\textbf{p}+\textbf{q}} t+i \textbf{q}\cdot\textbf{x}}
$$
where $\textbf{p}=(p_x,p_y,p_z)$ is constant and
$$
E_{\textbf{p}+\textbf{q}} = \sqrt{|\textbf{p}+\textbf{q}|^2+m^2}\,.
$$
Thank you very much for any help!

Comment: Substitute $\textbf{k}:=\textbf{p}+\textbf{q}$, go to polar coordinates, then integrate out both angles to get $$\frac{4\pi}{x}\exp(-i\textbf{p}\cdot\textbf{x})\int_0^\infty\frac{k\sin(kx)\exp(-iE_\textbf{k}t)}{\sqrt{E_\textbf{k}(E_\textbf{k}+m)}}dk.$$I'm not sure we can achieve much more. For example, $k=m\tanh u$ probably won't help because of a $\sqrt{\sec t(1+\sec t)}$ factor in the integrand's denominator.

Comment: @J.G. That integral is divergent. Consider the scaling at large $k$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the insights. I am actually suspecting this should give something proportional to $\delta^{(3)}(\textbf{p}-\textbf{q})$ but I haven't been able to clarify this yet. The behaviour for large $k$ does seem to point in this direction though.